# Python - How do you strip out duplicate xml tags? Or just parse out the first occurrence of an xml tag?

Tags: python, xml, string, tags, repeat

I have just retrieved an xml file from sec.gov, and it has the same xml tag with it's corresponding feed tag repeated about 5 times and I only need to get the first occurrence.

So it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <author>
      <email>webmaster@sec.gov</email>
      <name>Webmaster</name>
    </author>
    <company-info>
      <addresses>
        <address type="mailing">
          <city>CAMBRIDGE</city>
          <state>MA</state>
        </address>
    </company-info>
  </feed>
```

Then again, the same object right below it in the same file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <author>
      <email>webmaster@sec.gov</email>
      <name>Webmaster</name>
    </author>
    <company-info>
      <addresses>
        <address type="mailing">
          <city>CAMBRIDGE</city>
          <state>MA</state>
        </address>
    </company-info>
  </feed>
```

And again, the same object right below it in the same file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <author>
      <email>webmaster@sec.gov</email>
      <name>Webmaster</name>
    </author>
    <company-info>
      <addresses>
        <address type="mailing">
          <city>CAMBRIDGE</city>
          <state>MA</state>
        </address>
    </company-info>
  </feed>
```

It goes on like 5 times.

This is also causing an error when eventually I try to build it into an object, because I get the error:

```
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
    Extra content at the end of the document
```

How can I strip out only the first xml tag, with it's corresponding feed tag?  Or delete the other occurrences?

Here is what I currently have, starting with just trying to get the first xml tag:

```
finalXMLString = request.content.decode('utf-8')

xmlPattern = '(\<\?xml.*\?\>?){1}'
parsedXMLTag = re.search(xmlPattern, finalXMLString)

print(parsedXMLTag.group(1))
```

But that prints out the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

It won't just print out the 1st occurrence. I need it to print out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

Comment: The whole file is invalid XML as it can only contain 1 XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>`

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to just parse out the 1st occurrence xml tag with it's feed tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3, get first instance of the XML

```
import itertools as it
filename='list1.txt'
decl='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>'
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for key,group in it.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith(decl)):
        if not key:
            group = list(group)
            print(decl + '\n' + ''.join(group))
            break
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <author>
      <email>webmaster@sec.gov</email>
      <name>Webmaster</name>
    </author>
    <company-info>
      <addresses>
        <address type="mailing">
          <city>CAMBRIDGE</city>
          <state>MA</state>
        </address>
    </company-info>
  </feed>
```

If reading from a variable `x`

```
decl='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>'
for key,group in it.groupby(x.splitlines(),lambda line: line.startswith(decl)):
    if not key:
        group = list(group)
        print(decl + '\n' + '\n'.join(group))
        break
```

Comment: Hi LMC, thanks so much.  I tried replacing the "open(filename, 'r')" with my variable, finalXMLString and it crashed.  How can I do this without reading a file?

Comment: @BrentHeigold added reading from string.

Comment: Hi LMC, thank you I really appreciate this.  I'm sorry but that didn't work, it still printed out all occurrences of the xml tag, followed by each's feed tag.

Comment: is that python3?

Comment: Hi LMC, that's right it's python 3.5.2.

Comment: @BrentHeigold Try setting decl='<?xml version="1.0"' or even decl='<?xml'